# Visio add nested sublanes

Tags: microsoft-visio

I had a look at this question [How to nest swimlanes in a Cross-Functional Flowchart Visio 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/716546/how-to-nest-swimlanes-in-a-cross-functional-flowchart-visio-2013)

I am trying to add nested swimlanes but I can add only sub lane but not the sub -> sub lanes. I need something like this mentioned in the above link
[image: Desired Swimlane]

Some answers provided ion the above link but not working for me.

I would like to be able to be able to have swimlanes like:

- Supplier
- - Marketing
- - - Pre-Sales
- - - Post-Sales

But I can go only as far as Marketing level only.